# Form not POSTing values

Tags: php, html, forms

**Form:**

```
<form id="register" method="POST" action="pro/register.php">
    <input type="text" maxlength="30" placeholder="Username" id="user" /><br />
    <input type="email" maxlength="64" placeholder="Email" id="email" /><br />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pass1" /><br />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="pass2" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Register" id="submit_register" />
</form>
```

**`pro/register.php` page**:

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
$pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

//Debug only
echo "<strong>Details:</strong><br>";
echo $user.", ".$email.", ".$pass1.", ".$pass2."<br>";

if($pass1!==$pass2){
    header('Location:../login.php?alert=pass');
    exit;
}

$hash = hash('sha256', $pass);

include "../inc/functions.php";

$salt = createSalt();
$hash = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash);

include "../inc/connect.php";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` 
                (`username`,`email`,`password`,`salt`,`pic`) 
                VALUES (:username,:email,:password,:salt,:pic)");
$stmt->bindParam(':username',$user);
$stmt->bindParam(':email',$email);
$stmt->bindParam(':password',$hash);
$stmt->bindParam(':salt',$salt);
$stmt->bindParam(':pic',$pic);
$stmt->execute();
$dbh=NULL;

header('Location:../login.php?alert=newreg');
```

**Output when form is posted:**

```
Details:
, , ,
```

Comment: What if you add `name` to the elements?

Comment: You have no names set for any of the inputs...

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I thought it took the `ID` values.

Comment: @BenPearlKahan You may also encounter another problem. Try adding `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` on top of `$user = $_POST['user'];` just in case you do - it's happened before.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
<input type="text" maxlength="30" placeholder="Username" id="user" name="user"/><br />
```

try adding the name field.

Comment: @BenPearlKahan As a general rule, use Ids for javascript/css and Names for forms

Answer (score 5):

You must include the 'name' attribute in your form inputs, this is what determines where the value goes in $_POST.